# PayPal 500 Error Java Null Pointer Exception Error when submitting payment using AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, paypal

I am trying to initiate a PayPal payment using Ajax, I have managed to get my OAuth Bearer Access Token and have used that to create an AJAX query to request the payment, however when I submit I get the following error

```
<ns1:XMLFault xmlns:ns1="http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/xformat"><ns1:faultstring xmlns:ns1="http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/xformat">java.lang.NullPointerException</ns1:faultstring></ns1:XMLFault>
```

The code that I am running is:

```
dataObject = {
                    "transactions": [{
                        "amount": {
                            "currency":"USD",
                            "total":"12"
                        },
                        "description":"creating a payment"
                    }],
                    "payer": {
                        "payment_method":"paypal"
                    },
                    "intent":"sale",
                    "redirect_urls": {
                        "cancel_url":"https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/pay_paypal/curl?cancel=true",
                        "return_url":"https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/pay_paypal/curl?success=true"
                    }
                   };
        $.ajax({
            headers: {
                 "Accept": "application/json",
                 "Accept-Language": "en_US",
                 "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessCode,
            },
            url: "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment",
            method: "POST",
            data: dataObject,                   
            complete: function(result) {
                if (console) { console.log('response: ' + JSON.stringify(result)); };
            },
            error: function(err) {              
                alert(err);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution, error in the headers converting from the PayPal Curl documentation, for the Ajax you need to explicitly state the content type

```
"Content-Type": "application/json"
```